# Distributing an Electron app on Windows, Mac and Linux

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron, electron-builder

I've spend my weekend experimenting with Electron and this caused a few questions and dilemmas in my head.

I cloned the following Github repository to test with:
[electron-vue-typescript-starter](https://github.com/fwouts/electron-vue-typescript-starter.git)

This project uses `electron-builder` to build the project, based on the host platform you're developing on. Since I'm developing on Windows it builds an `.exe` file.

Apart from the `.exe` there are also some other files. The following files were made by `electron-builder` on `windows`:

```
| win-unpacked
|--- (lots of DDL's + electron-application.exe)

--- electron-builder.yaml  
--- electron-application setup 0.0.0.exe
--- electron-application setup 0.0.0.exe.blockmap
--- latest.yml
```

**Question 1:** If I want to distribute the application for public usage, what should users download? The `.exe` setup only? Or do they need some/all of the other files aswell?

After setting up a macOS VM I've managed to build the application for the `darwin` platform too. The following files were made by `electron-builder` on `darwin`:

```
| github
|--- latest-mac.json
| mac
|--- electron-application.app

--- electron-builder.yaml  
--- electron-application-0.0.0-mac.zip
--- electron-application-0.0.0.dmg
--- electron-application-0.0.0.dmg.blockmap
--- latest-mac.yml
```

**Question 2:** What do the users need from above to use/install the application on the `darwin` platform?

**Question 3:** I haven't build the application for `linux` yet. But how do I distribute the `linux` edition? Would this be similar to the `darwin` one?

Note: I have read some parts of the `electron-builder` documentation but it it's really abstract and doesn't explain (as far as I could see) how someone would distribute the build contents.

The cleanest way would be a single `.exe` file for `windows` and a single `.zip` or `.dmg` for `darwin`. But what are the other files for? What should I do with them, because they are there for a reason, right?

Answer (score 0):

For distribution, you need to provide an installer (msi) for windows user.

- You need to follow below link, which will answer all your questions.

[electron-packager-tutorial](https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-packager-tutorial/)

[electron-windows-installer](https://www.christianengvall.se/electron-windows-installer/)

Above tutorial also provide information about creating Debian package.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! As I described in my question above, I'm able to create packages for windows (NSIS setup with `electron-builder`) and for darwin/mac (ZIP with the Applicaiton inside and DMG). Im particularly curious about the other build-files from `electron-builder`. What are these for and do users need them?

Comment: @Vincent Hey, did u find an answer to your question about specifics files for darwin like the .blockmap one ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to serve them with the entire folder contents. When they run the .exe, it references the other files to complete the installation